# Ger error when trying to run parallel builds on maven release prepare and perform task?

Tags: java, maven, build, continuous-integration, pom.xml

I've found some ways to increase the speed of our standard maven builds such as only building modules that have changed and utilising parallel builds. For the task:

`clean release:prepare release:perform`

It takes a while and I'd like to speed up. It seems the parallel builds doesn't work I get an error.
The error I get when running parallel builds is:

```
[ERROR] NullPointerException
[ERROR] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when running command:

```
clean -T 1C release:prepare release:perform
```

This seems to be the only error I get - not sure why? This isn't a problem when I run a normal build with this flag.

Also any suggestions on how else to speed up this process? I assume I could skip tests and they're already being done on the builds on the dev branch before it's merged with master?

edit: Have added below error message with debug flag:

```
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.calcImports (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:470)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.multiThreadedProjectTaskSegmentBuild (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.build (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.calcImports (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:470)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR]
```

Comment: It does not make sense to run `-T 1C` for release cause `release:prepare` runs a single goal and `release:perform` as well. The question is: Would you like to run the build itself with `-T 1C` which you have to configure differently. Apart from that the NPE should not happen...can you show which version of Maven and maven-release-plugin you are using?

Comment: The release plugin is maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 and maven is 3.5.2

Comment: Please run the build with `-X` and publish the full stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Can't publish the full stack trace as private info on but have put the error with the debug flag on in the above

Comment: Please upgrade to most recent Maven Version 3.6.3 ...second running your build in release build in that way will not work...but that's a different story let us solve the first problem...

Comment: Ok upgrading seems to work actually - I've cancelled as don't want to change the version number/deploy anything and do cleanup on that but will check next time I have to do a release

Comment: Khmarbaise feel free to comment on this post with your suggestion (basically copy my post) and I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @khmarbaise for suggesting the fix. This can be solved with latest maven version and can be seen described in the release notes for version 3.6.1

http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html